# "d'avec les" vs "des"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I encountered this sentence:

"*Il faut s’astreindre régulièrement à arracher les baobabs dès qu'on les distingue **d'avec** les rosiers auxquels ils ressemblent beaucoup quand ils sont très jeunes*" (Le petit prince).

I cannot understand the usage of *d'avec*. Wouldn't the expression *...dès qu'on les distingue **des** rosiers...* be more correct? Does the former entails some sutlety in terms of meaning or is it just a fancy, more archaic way to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it right, it's a dated way to say *...distingue des rosiers*.

The [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avec) also gives this definition :

> − *D'avec*, loc. prép. [Construit avec certains verbes (tels que *divorcer*, *retirer*, etc.) pour marquer de façon plus positive la différence ou la séparation existant entre deux pers., entre deux choses, entre une pers. et une ou plusieurs choses] :
> 4. Dans les ruminans, les fosses moyennes sont à peine distinguées d'**avec** la fosse antérieure. Cuvier, *Leçons d'anat. comp.*,t. 2, 1805, p. 39.

An even more archaic form would have been:

...pour qu'on les distingue d'[avecque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avecque#frm) les rosiers.